# Eclipse regex search not working

Tags: regex, eclipse

I am trying to find method usages of the following format `<obj>.Apply(<arg1>,<arg2>)`

So I search for this regex in my project resources: `\.Apply\([^,]*?,[^,]*?\)`

but this does not work.

As well as accepting `<obj>.Apply(<arg1>,<arg2>)` it also accepts for examlpe `<obj>.Apply()`.

I have verified the regex works on regex101.com so I am not sure why this isn't working in eclipse?

The eclipse I am using is Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers, Version: Oxygen.3 Release (4.7.3), Build id: 20180308-1800, The project I am searching is a Go project using the GoClipse plugin.

Comment: try this \.Apply\([^)]+\)

Answer (score 1):

If you want only match `.Apply(a1,a2)` this part do this :

```
\.Apply\([^,)]+,[^,)]+[^,)]
```

https://regex101.com/r/ILKcsT/3/

Comment: but the problem with that regex is that it matches 1 arg, 3 args, 4, etc...

Also my regex should work. It doesn't matter that * matches empty because I have specified that there must be 1 comma between the brackets which should effectively return function calls that use only 2 args

Comment: @LostCrotchet let me know what you want exactly

Comment: @LostCrotchet you regex will not match , inside , suppose there is empty it is acceptable why    [,^]* this part maybe or not then there is ? and if that part not there it will be like this ,? so here means if there is comma or not , you get it

Comment: @LostCrotchet see another regex

Comment: the problem with the new regex is that it doesn't match <obj>.Apply(a1,a2) .. I only meant <arg1> and <arg2> as being abstract placeholders for any variable names

Comment: @LostCrotchet you should explain that from the beginning i will update a code

Comment: The updated regex still does not work. After fiddling around with it, I think what you're trying to do is \.Apply\([^,)]+,[^,)]+\) , but even though this works in regex101 (as does my originally mentioned regex), it does not work in the eclipse regex search functionality.